# registerModule with dependencies

Tags: angularjs, mean-stack, meanjs

I'm building an app with MEAN.JS and I'm trying to use a controller from another module. I've found that I can do this with dependency injection:

```
angular.module(‘MyModule’, [‘Dependency’]);
```

But the way modules are created in MEAN.JS is:

```
ApplicationConfiguration.registerModule('MyModule');
```

And I can't just pass a second parameter to `registerModule`. So, how should I do this? Do I have to use both methods? Am I doing it wrong?

---

#### Example

I want to add a new model: `Campaign`. `Campaigns` are created by admins only, but can be seen by the "campaign owner" (another `User`). The create campaign form should list available Users, so the admin can select the one that's going to be the "owner" of that `Campaign`.
The problem is, the create campaign form is controlled by `CampaignsController`, how can I list `Users`? I've used another controller (`UsersController`) and thats the problem, it is undefined because we are in the `Campaign` module.

---

#### EDIT:

The problem was grunt autorestarting the app incorrectly:
I moved the controller from one module (folder) to another, but grunt was still trying to load it from the old path, and thus failing: Controller not found. I thought the problem was dependency injection, but you only have to close grunt (Ctrl+C) and run it again. Problem solved.
Anyways, thanks for the answer @gilBirman cause it is correct: there is no need to inject anything with MEANJS.

Comment: all angular modules injected main module automatically... so you do not need to inject controller to another module to use it there you already have it...

Comment: I'm getting a `'UsersController' is not a function, got undefined` error when using `UsersController` from my custom module, what does it mean then? Searching for the error all the answers are "missing dependency" related, but all about angular without MEAN.JS

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**MEAN.js makes all the modules registered via `registerModule` available to all other modules in your app** by adding it as a dependency to the main app called **mean**. Here's the part of the MEAN.js source code that does this:

```
var applicationModuleName = 'mean';
....
// Add a new vertical module
var registerModule = function(moduleName) {
    // Create angular module
    angular.module(moduleName, []);

    // Add the module to the AngularJS configuration file
    angular.module(applicationModuleName).requires.push(moduleName);
};
```

So  you're on the right track, however it sounds like you are trying to *inject a controller*. However, **in angular, controllers are not injectable**. You can inject *services*, *factories*, *values*, and *constants*.

Comment: Hello, does this mean, that every module should be a dependency of the mean-(root)-Module? How do I setup dependencis on submodules?

Answer (score 2):

First create your own module for example:

```
angular.module('app.controllers', []) - angular module with controllers.
```

then add controller to that module:

```
angular.module('app.controllers', [])
       .controller('dashboard.admin.account.controller', ['$scope', ($scope) { .... }]);
```

then create global module which will bind to your markup:

```
angular.module('app', [
  'app.controllers'
  'ui.router',
  'ngAnimate'
]);
```

then bootstrap your global module to markup:

```
domReady(function () {
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
});
```

Now you can use your controller.

Comment: and what should I do with `registerModule`? should I remove it? remember I'm using MEAN.JS, things are a little bit different: https://github.com/meanjs/mean

Comment: I have no competent knowledge mean.js, but documentation tells that angular modules need use like i described http://screencast.com/t/H1QWDJjfZ5.

Comment: @VitaliyKhudonogov From which URL API Documentation i can check this screenshot