# AngularJS + NodeJS - Error when invoking injected service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, dependency-injection

I have two modules in a node/express/angular application, order and users. In the users module I have a very simple service:

```
angular.module('users').factory('UsersRest', ['$q', '$log', '$http',
    function($q, $log, $http) {

        var getUserInfo = function(userid) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http.get('/proxy/rest/user/'+ userid).
                success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    var userdetail = data;
                    deferred.resolve(userdetail);
                });
            return  deferred.promise;
        };


        // public API
        return {
            getUserInfo: getUserInfo
        };


    }
]);
```

I'd like to use this service in my order module. So when I register the order module I use

```
ApplicationConfiguration.registerModule('order', ['users']);
```

and in another service in my order module I call it by using

```
angular.module('order').factory('OrderService', ['$q','$http','$log', 'UsersRest',
    function($q,$http,$log, UsersRest) {

        // stuff

        var update = function(order_request){

            var userdetail = UsersRest.getUserInfo(window.user.id).then(function (data) {
                $log.info('information about user retrieved.');
                return data;
            });

            // some other stuff

        };

        // Public API
        return {
            update: update
        };
    }
]);
```

But when I try it, I get the following error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: UsersRestProvider <- UsersRest <- OrderService
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$injector/unpr?p0=UsersRestProvider%20%3C-%20UsersRest%20%3C-<section data-ui-view="" class="ng-scope" data-ng-animate="1">rderService
    at REGEX_STRING_REGEXP (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:68:12)
    at http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:4262:19
    at Object.getService [as get] (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:4409:39)
    at http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:4267:45
    at getService (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:4409:39)
    at Object.invoke (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:4441:13)
    at Object.enforcedReturnValue [as $get] (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:4303:37)
    at Object.invoke (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:4450:17)
    at http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:4268:37
    at getService (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:4409:39)
```

What's the matter there? Is kind of injection problem?

**EDIT**
Here's how I register the users module:

```
ApplicationConfiguration.registerModule('users',['tmh.dynamicLocale']);
```

Comment: That Error implies that "OrderService" Does not know what "UsersRest" is, make sure the modules are properly registered/created

Comment: Please include your registration of the users module.

Comment: Not sure of your file setup but if those factories are in separate files are they included in your index.html?

Comment: @Manatax I've added the registration of the other module.

Comment: I'm assuming registerModule is a custom method that wraps on the module registration from angular?

Comment: it's the way MEAN.JS registers modules, as stated in this question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24605798/registermodule-with-dependencies)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
    angular.module('order').factory('OrderService', ['$q','$http','$log',
    function($q,$http,$log, UsersRest) {
...
    }
```

give UsersRest only in the function as a parameter and not in the array too

Comment: I believe the user service should be injected in the order service in order to use it on the function itself.

Comment: if he does any kind of minifiying then he is going to get errors you need the 'UsersRest' in the array for the minifier.

Comment: @ChadWatkins you're right, I need to put the injection even in the array

Answer (score 0):

The answer was pretty easy. In fact, grunt didn't recognise the injection. Just **Ctrl+C** and **grunt** again did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try to register your module in [this way](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.module):

```
angular.module('users',['tmh.dynamicLocale']);
angular.module('order', ['users']);
```

And make sure that you are registering your modules before you use them.